# Is having Store getters with Promise an anti-pattern in Reflux

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I'm getting into reflux and am embracing the single direction flow.

That said, I'm struggling with the idea of Components having to fire an action just to get data from the store. This is in a lot of examples I have seen, but it seems odd when requesting data rather than being informed there is new data.

Here is sorta what I am thinking:
The `Component` initializes with a loading state.
The `Component` then calls a getter on the `Store` that returns a `Promise` with a `success` callback that populates the `Component` state with the new data and a `reject` that populates `Component` state with an error. If something updates the `Store`, I continue to `listenTo` the `Store`, but my callback is the same `success` that is used in the initial `Promise`.

This seems like a straight forward implementation of Promises, but is it an anti-pattern in Reflux? I understand we don't want to mutate data in the `Store`, but I'm having a hard time seeing why an `Action` need to be involved in simple getting.

Can someone set me straight?

Comment: I use a slight modification of the flux pattern... on the store i implement a getData() function that returns the stores properties... on each component I call store.getData() for my state. and in the component did mount I add my change listener to the store so when I make a change you just emit the change and the components capture it and handle the change appropriately. Seems to be a very simple but good use of the system and doesn't go through an action. incase you want to try it out. makes more sense to me

Answer (score 1):

I use an action that is listened to by the api.store. The api.store is the only place that accesses the util/api.js object that actually handles calls to the server. When the server responds another action is emitted that is listened to by the data.store for that data. The store will then emit that is listened to by the control component. The control component then requests the data from the store. It may seem convoluted but the separation of concerns makes for very maintainable code.

```js
'use strict';

import React  from 'react';
import ReactDom  from 'react-dom';

import AppCtrl from './components/app.ctrl.js';
import Actions from './flux/Actions';
import ApiStore from './flux/Api.Store';

window.ReactDom = ReactDom;

Actions.apiInit();

ReactDom.render( <AppCtrl />, document.getElementById('react') );
```

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import ApiFct from './../utils/api.js';

let ApiStoreObject = {
 newData: {
  "React version": "0.14",
  "Project": "ReFluxSuperAgent",
  "currentDateTime": new Date().toLocaleString()
 },
 listenables: Actions,
 apiInit() { ApiFct.setData(this.newData); },
 apiInitDone() { ApiFct.getData(); },
 apiSetData(data) { ApiFct.setData(data); }
}
const ApiStore = Reflux.createStore(ApiStoreObject);
export default ApiStore;
```

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import Actions from '../flux/Actions';

let uri = 'http://localhost:3500';

module.exports = {
 getData() { request.get(uri + '/routes/getData').end((err, res) => { this.gotData(res.body); }); },
 gotData(data) { Actions.gotData1(data); Actions.gotData2(data); Actions.gotData3(data); },
 setData(data) { request.post('/routes/setData').send(data).end((err, res) => { Actions.apiInitDone(); }) },
};
```

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
 init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
 data1: {},
 listenables: Actions,
 mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
 onGotData1: _GotData,
 onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
 getData1() { return this.data1; },
 getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
 getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

const getState = () => {
 return {
  Data1: BasicStore.getData1(),
  Data2: BasicStore.getData2(),
  Data3: BasicStore.getData3()
 };
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let data1 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data1, null, 2);
  let data2 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data2, null, 2);
  let data3 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data3, null, 2);
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux with SuperAgent<br/><br/>
    Data1: {data1}<br/><br/>
    Data2: {data2}<br/><br/>
    Data3: {data3}<br/><br/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount = () => { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange); }
 componentWillUnmount = () => { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange = (id) => {
  switch (id) {
   case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
   case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
   case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
   default: this.setState(getState());
  }
 }
}
```

From https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns.

Comment: This is exactly the pattern that we use (with success). There's one thing and that is that when using reflux, the documentation states to send the data when using 'this.trigger(data)'. However, our stores do contain multiple data-items and therefore we only supply the name of the item that has changed.